# Observers in the same frame of reference

Tags: general-relativity, reference-frames, observers

Let’s suppose that $\gamma, \gamma^{*} : I\rightarrow U\subset M$ are worldlines of two observers and $\{e_{\mu}\}^4_{\mu = 1}\in TU$ is a frame field. Then we know that for the observers to use the same frame field, they must have zero relative velocity.

Can this be stated by parallel-transporting $e_{0}(\gamma(\lambda))\in T_{\gamma(\lambda)}U$ to $T_{\gamma^{*}(\lambda)}U$ along a curve $s$ and imposing that $P^{\gamma(\lambda)}_{\gamma^{*}(\lambda)}(s)(e_{0}(\gamma(\lambda))-e_{0}(\gamma^{*}(\lambda)) = 0$? However, there seems to be a problem that this will be path-dependent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Then we know that for the observers to use the same frame field, they must have zero relative velocity

This is true if the frame field is inertial, but it is not true in general. In curved spacetime this cannot be a requirement for the exact reason that you showed: relative velocity is path dependent.

Comment: If two observers use the same frame field, can we say that they use the same coordinate chart as orthonormality requires an inner product $\langle\cdot, \cdot\rangle$, and which depends on choice of local coordinates?

Comment: @Soldier the metric is more fundamental than a coordinate chart. The metric is a bilinear form, and so using the inner product does not specify a coordinate chart. Also, coordinate charts need not be orthonormal